# What is the topic of this maths question?

Tags: functions

I've come across this maths question that I've never seen before and I wanted to know what topic does it cover so that I can research how to solve this question. (Solving this question is optional for any question answerers)

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$f((x,y)) := x^2 + 2y^2 - 3xy$, for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

The value of $f_x((0,0)) + f_y((0,0)) + f_{xy}((0,0))$ is:

Comment: Can you find e.g. the function $f_x$? Do you know what the notation means?

Comment: @drhab $f_x$ would equal $2x$ at $f_x(0,0)$ right? Also I believe that $f_y$ would equal to $4y$ at $f_y(0,0)$. I'm a bit stuck on $f_{xy}$

Comment: $f_x(x,y)=2x-3y$ (differentiating wrt $x$ where $y$ is considered to be constant) and consequently $f_x(0,0)=2\times0-3\times0=0$. For finding $f_{xy}$ you should differentiate $f_x$ wrt to $y$ and consider $x$ as a constant at that time. That results in $f_{xy}(x,y)=-3$

Comment: @drhab Yes precisely, so then after inputing (0,0) both $f_y(0,0) $ and $f_x(0,0) $ end up equalling to 0 right? what about the $f_{xy}$?

Comment: That is right. See former comment for $f_{xy}$. Also it is good to know that in cases like this we always have $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ (order of differentiation does not count).

Comment: ok so I just reviewed a youtube video. So I believe that $f_{xy}$ at (0,0) ends up being -3? Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. It concerns so-called "partial differentiation".

Comment: Awesome, thanks for confirming @drhab, now I have a basic understanding of tackling similar questions.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple calculus. The subscripts indicate partial derivatives: $f_x$ means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $f_y$ means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, and $f_{xy}$ means $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$.

You are being asked to evaluate each of these at $(0,0)$ and add them up.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a fairly basic exercise in multivariable calculus. $f_x$, for example, denotes the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$.